# Apollo nodejs server; How to get query argument in when writing a plugin?

Tags: node.js, apollo-server

My objective is to write an Apollo plugin, that can save a specific input type on my context, for *all* queries.

The input is called "QueryOptions".

```
input QueryOptions {
    tenant: ID
}

# example query
somePath(queryOptions: {
  tenant: "some-tenant"
})
#example query 2
someOtherPath(queryOptions: {
  tenant: "some-tenant"
})
```

Would it be able to determine the value of `tenant`, in an Apollo plugin? Maybe in the `didResolveOperation` hook?

Thanks for your input - currently I solve the issue by setting the tenant property on the context as the first thing on my resolvers.